# How to install the scanner of Canon MF4750 multi-device?

Tags: drivers, canon, scanner, sane

I am using 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and bought a Canon i-Sensys MF4750 printer + scanner + fax. There is a driver on the official Canon homepage only for the printer, and that works fine. But I need the scanner too...

The scanner is not recognized automatically (I connect it by USB). I installed SANE, but still doesn't work. I followed the steps here:
[Troubleshooting sane - Adding a Scanner that is not auto-detected](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane_Troubleshooting#Adding_a_Scanner_that_is_not_auto-detected).

when I type sane-find-scanner than it finds it as follows:
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9, product=0x2774) at libusb:002:005

But when I try to scan (SimpleScan, XSANE, Scanimage...) it just does not work (no scanner).

How can I get to work it? How can I get a driver for this scanner (probably SANE is not supporting my model)?

Please write in very simple way, I have very poor knowledge about Linux systems...

Answer (score 2):

**1. Printer driver:**

[Canon i-SENSYS MF4750 - Support - Download drivers, software and manuals](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF4750.aspx?type=download&softwaredetailid=tcm:13-1135803&os=Linux&language=)

**2. Scaner driver :**

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev build-essential libsane-dev

sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Download latest sane source code

```
git clone git://git.debian.org/sane/sane-backends.git

cd sane-backends

./configure

make

sudo make install
```

**3. Set Permissions for USB (allows you to scan without using sudo)**

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
```

Change..

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ... , MODE="0664"
```

To..

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ... , MODE="0666"
```

Reboot.

```
sane-find-scanner -f

scanimage -L
```

Enjoy !!!

Comment: This answer looks to take a guess on what the problem actually is without second checking if the solution resides in the latest code. It is worth a try but maybe you should mention why you think this will solve the problem.