# Using the scanner of Canon i-SENSYS MF4380dn via network

Tags: networking, drivers, canon, scanner

I switched today from Windows to Linux. I have a Canon i-SENSYS MF4380dn multifunction printer that is available via network (ethernet). At the [Canon site](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf4380dn.aspx) I could find the printer driver and I was able to register the device as network printer. Now I want to install/configure the scanner. I tried different ways via sane etc., e. g. this one: [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514591/how-to-install-the-scanner-of-canon-mf4750-multi-device) but I don't really get how to do the configuration for the network mode. Simple Scan tells me that there is no scanner reachable. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so SANE is the open-source support for scanning; http://www.sane-project.org/ and if one drills into it, they feel your device is supported; in both the stable; and development variants; however I have seen several cases where adding the development ppa helps; so I suggest that; to add this,  there are two commands `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-git` and `sudo apt-get update` as here https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git

Comment: there is a file called pixma.conf that lives in /etc/sane.d/ and you may well need to edit that; to add your network address and if you use the text editor the command would `gksudo gedit /etc/sane.d/pixma.conf` to open it so you can change it; to just look at the command is `gedit /etc/sane.d/pixma.conf`so perhaps do that first so you can see what is involved; this link covers this area https://askubuntu.com/questions/75887/how-do-i-add-a-canon-pixma-mx860-network-printer

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I added `bjnp://192.168.2.199` (thats the ip of my device) to the `pixma.conf`. If I try to find my scanner via `sudo sane-find-scanner` or `scanimage -L`it will not work. I already pulled and installed the sane stuff. Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo scanimage -L

[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000)

[bjnp] bjnp_init_device_structure: Cannot read mac address, skipping this scanner

[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000)

[bjnp] add_scanner: ERROR - Cannot read scanner make & model: bjnp://192.168.2.199:8612/timeout=1000`

Comment: I wondered which version of Ubuntu? you have installed; I ask because the latest; 17.10 seems to have issues with scanners: I have now seen several posts where issues are described;

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Any ideas or at least a hint to go ahead?

Comment: if you subscribe to the SANE mailing list and see if they can help http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/sane-devel

Comment: Ok, thanks. This device is not supported by SANE.